# Single Sign On service hangs when configuring it

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am trying to create and configure the Bluemix Single Sign On service and I am facing issues.

I create it unbound of any app, and when trying to setup it on the first dialog (provide a service name which will be part of its URL) it gets hanged. The browser is unresponsive for 1 minute or so and finally it fails with error message: "env: Client internal Error"

I am facing the same issue with Firefox 38.0.5, Chrome 43.0.2357.81m and IE 11.0.9600.17801

Any suggestion? Searching the forums I found as recommendation to clean browser cache and cookies. I already did it with no success.

EDITED: In parallel, I added as manager and developer another colleague to my Bluemix Space and it worked fine to him. So it seems it fails with my user which also is manager and developer but it exists in other spaces, etc...

Any thing I can check to narrow the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on yesterday there have been a maintenance/upgrade activity so probably it your problem could be related to this.
Could you check again if it is working right now?